# How to solve this error, Uncaught Error: 36.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0, 33.0.0, UNVERSIONED

Tags: react-native

I am working on React native new project when I enter npm start I got this error on my Mobile with blue screen Uncaught Error: 36.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0, 33.0.0, UNVERSIONED. I tried to solve this error by using these commands

npm install (for node module)
expo update
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
npm start

But It didn't work, please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3112), you can try to delete the expo client on the emulator, and run the project again. This should work.

[Here's](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/) the documentation of how to upgrade your expo version, but i think you don't will need it, because you're on the latest version.